# BotFramework - No recording icon in Bot Emulator

Tags: botframework

Working on a voice bot that will take as input the voice, I have two concerns.

Technology(.net), Framework(BotFrameWork v4)

1. The Bot Emulator doesn't contain the recording icon, how to bring that. If by putting the microsoft app id and password, It shows up then where to get these credentials for local development and testing.
2. How to give the response input to the bot, v4 documentation is a way too confusing for me, I would like someone to tell me specifically what im looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your app id and password to the development endpoint in your bot file to enable the microphone feature on the emulator.

If your bot file has a production endpoint, you can likely find the app id and password there. Most bot files are encrypted, so I would recommend retrieving the id and password through the emulator. In the emulator, right click on production under the Endpoint section on the left and then select Edit Configuration. This should open a window where you can copy the app id and password.

[image]

If your bot file does not have a production endpoint and you don't have the app id and password stored somewhere else, you will have to follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to register your bot on the Azure Portal.

Now that you have the app id and password for your bot, you need to add them to the development endpoint in your bot file. Once again, most bot files are encrypted, so open your bot in the BotFramework Emulator. Right click on development under the Endpoint section on the left, and select Edit Configuration. It will open a screen where you can add the Application id and password that we retrieved in the previous step.

Now run your bot and connect to it in the emulator. You should be able to use the microphone to talk to your bot. When the user talks to the bot, the emulator will convert the user's voice to text and will send the message to the bot as an activity like any other interaction the user has with the bot.

[image]